# Every reinstalling from scracth this warning keep showing. dpkg --verify

Tags: boot, apt, dpkg, cups-lpd

```
dpkg: aviso: cups-browsed: não foi possível abrir /usr/lib/cups/backend/implicitclass para o hash: Permission denied
```

****??5??????**   /usr/lib/cups/backend/implicitclass**
**??5??????   /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-31-generic**

```
dpkg: aviso: geoclue-2.0: não foi possível abrir /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/geoclue-2.0.pkla para o hash: Permission denied
```

**??5??????   /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/geoclue-2.0.pkla**

```
dpkg: aviso: systemd: não foi possível abrir /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/systemd-networkd.pkla para o hash: Permission denied
??5??????   /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/systemd-networkd.pkla
dpkg: aviso: network-manager: não foi possível abrir /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pkla para o hash: Permission denied
??5??????   /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pkla
dpkg: aviso: linux-modules-5.8.0-33-generic: não foi possível abrir /boot/System.map-5.8.0-33-generic para o hash: Permission denied
??5??????   /boot/System.map-5.8.0-33-generic
dpkg: aviso: linux-image-5.8.0-33-generic: não foi possível abrir /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-33-generic para o hash: Permission denied
??5??????   /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-33-generic
dpkg: aviso: sudo: não foi possível abrir /etc/sudoers para o hash: Permission denied
??5?????? c /etc/sudoers
dpkg: aviso: sudo: não foi possível abrir /etc/sudoers.d/README para o hash: Permission denied
??5?????? c /etc/sudoers.d/README
dpkg: aviso: ppp: não foi possível abrir /etc/chatscripts/gprs para o hash: Permission denied
??5?????? c /etc/chatscripts/gprs
dpkg: aviso: ppp: não foi possível abrir /etc/chatscripts/pap para o hash: Permission denied
??5?????? c /etc/chatscripts/pap
dpkg: aviso: gnome-initial-setup: não foi possível abrir /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/gnome-initial-setup.pkla para o hash: Permission denied
??5??????   /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/gnome-initial-setup.pkla
dpkg: aviso: linux-modules-5.8.0-31-generic: não foi possível abrir /boot/System.map-5.8.0-31-generic para o hash: Permission denied
??5??????   /boot/System.map-5.8.0-31-generic
dpkg: aviso: packagekit: não foi possível abrir /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/org.freedesktop.packagekit.pkla para o hash: Permission denied
??5??????   /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/org.freedesktop.packagekit.pkla
dpkg: aviso: cups-filters: não foi possível abrir /usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-brf para o hash: Permission denied
??5??????   /usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-brf
dpkg: aviso: policykit-desktop-privileges: não foi possível abrir /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla para o hash: Permission denied
??5??????   /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
dpkg: aviso: fwupd: não foi possível abrir /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/fwupd.pkla para o hash: Permission denied
??5??????   /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/fwupd.pkla
```

Should I ignore since it's not affecting my machine performance or try to dig it out?

```
~$ sudo dpkg --verify 

??5??????   /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-31-generic
```

Comment: use `sudo` to get permission and fix the Permission denied problem.

Comment: It's clear now, only last one.

Comment: Now to answer the question, may this help https://askubuntu.com/questions/792553/dpkg-v-what-does-the-output-mean#:~:text=dpkg%20%2DV%20or%20dpkg%20%2D%2D,failed%20any%20check%20are%20shown.

Comment: Yes, it's solved. Thanks.